# sendmail AUTH - block unsecure incoming

Tags: smtp, email-server, sendmail

I have a question regarding sendmail 8.14.4 running on CentOS 6:
Is it possible to disable only incoming AUTH requests and keep the outgoing AUTH running?
We had a PCI scan which came up with this issue. (accept AUTH attempts, they tested with EHLO)

On the scan results they say "Disable the plaintext authentication methods on your SMTP server for unencrypted" - does that mean we need to remove PLAIN and LOGIN? would that affect outgoing email authentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `p` to `confAUTH_OPTIONS` settings in your `sendmail.mc` file, generate new `sendmail.cf` file and restart or HUP sendmail daemon.

```
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS',`p')
```

It should block `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` authentication over unencrypted **incoming** connections.

You may use `grep AuthOptions /etc/mail/sendmail.cf` to check current settings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Here are the results (pasting only the part that changed) before: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-XXXXXXXXA
250 XXXB

AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6     After: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP

Comment: Would you consider this as fixed?

Comment: 1) With the above fix successfully applied sendmail **should not** offer `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` **before** `STARTTLS`  2) What is reported by `grep AuthOptions /etc/mail/sendmail.cf` ?  3) change you SMTP AUTH password - `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` are simple to decode.

Comment: Here is the output of the grep command: O AuthOptions=p   We are using authentication for external mail services (mandril - i see the details in /etc/mail/auth/client-info) so we need to make sure we don't break that part...

Comment: Have you restarted/reloaded sendmail server after changig sendmail.cf?

Comment: I restarted the service...

Comment: I noticed the following on my backup mc - don't those 2 cancel each other?:                                                         
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following allows relaying if the user authenticates, and disallows
dnl # plaintext authentication (PLAIN/LOGIN) on non-TLS links
dnl #
dnl define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl

Comment: Found the solution which was very close to your suggestion, I had to change the definition to define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS',`A p') rather then only p - works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I wrote "**Add** p to confAUTH_OPTIONS ..."